# Etags in Rails 5 with Phusion/Apache 2.4

Tags: passenger, apache2.4, ruby-on-rails-5.2

When using `fresh_when strong_etag: @collection` in a Rails view, the etag is generated before being gzipped by Apache, thus it lacks the "-gzip" suffix.

However, if Apache is set to gzip responses, the Etag that the browser sends will contain the "-gzip" suffix.

This may or may not be connected to using Phusion Passenger as the proxy server for Rails.

Suggested solutions include having Apache strip the "-gzip" suffix by adding `RequestHeader edit "If-None-Match" "^(.*)-gzip$" "$1"` to the site's directives. However, this does not appear to work as intended.

Is there another way to rewrite the header to strip the suffix so that Etags can be successfully compared?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished in Rails by adding a `before_action` to the Application controller (to affect all requests).

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :fix_etag_header

...

  private

  def fix_etag_header
    if request.headers["HTTP_IF_ONE_MATCH"]
      request.headers["HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH"].sub! "-gzip", ""
    end
  end
end
```

Obviously, this circumvents the directive that a compressed resource should have a unique Etag from the same resource uncompressed. That could cause issues if those aspects of an HTTP request are altered or addressed by other code.

However, in most instances, this is a "good enough" solution especially when considering that it requires only 6 lines.